# move list items using sharegate to archive list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

hi guys I am trying to move archive items from source list to target list using sharegate but all items are getting copied instead of moving.Have imported sharegate modules in powershell. Any ideas appreciated using sharegate UI or Powershell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is not possible by the tool, here is a reply from ShareGate though it is a year old :

April 26, 2019
Hi everyone.

I am glad to say that we are currently exploring the possibility to add an option to automatically make Read-only and/or Delete the source of migration if it goes errorless.

We’ll keep you updated with any news on this.

Cheers,

J-P

User voice link:

[Add a ''Move'' and Delete Option](https://feedback.sharegate.com/forums/912880-sharegate-desktop-suggestions/suggestions/19955185-add-a-move-and-delete-option)

As an alternate - you should develop and schedule a sample PowerShell script which should delete the particular list or library after the successful migration automatically.

Comment: Link does not work.